# VBA -How to get Internet Explorer dropdown item

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, html-select

I am having difficulty in getting the item for a dropdown from an Internet Explorer page. My ultimate goal is to loop through the items on the dropdown and complete some procedure.

Here is my code :

```
    'IE declare
    Public htmlbuttons As IHTMLElementCollection
    Public htmlbutton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Public HTMLINPUT As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Public HTMLDOC As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Public ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorerMedium
    
    
    
    Sub PrimeDownload()
    
    
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "Navigate to site"
    
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
    
        
    Set HTMLDOC = ie.Document
    
    ' Login to Acct
    HTMLDOC.getElementById("myusr_name").Value = "Username"
    HTMLDOC.getElementById("myusr_password").Value = "Password"
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    
    'Click login
    HTMLDOC.getElementById("sign-in-button").Click
    
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
    
    
    
    'NAVI to Reporting > Balances > SD Cash Reconcilation
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    ie.Navigate "Navigate to Page"
    
    Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Enter Account
   HTMLDOC.getElementsByClassName("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input")(0).Focus
    HTMLDOC.getElementsByClassName("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input")(0).selectedIndex = 2
    
    
    end Sub
```

I have also tried setting:
HTMLDOC.getElementsByClassName("custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left ui-autocomplete-input")(0).value = "the item" but unfortunately when I subsequently click the search button it will not select the item .

Here's an image of the HTML for the dropdown and the item

[Dropdown HTML DOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3flw.png)

[DropDown Item HTML DOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPjfs.png)

Comment: That's a `<ul>` element and not a `<select>`, so it has no `Value` or `selectedIndex` property...

Comment: there is a clearly visible select element -is that what you intended to select?

Comment: I intend to select an item listed on the dropdown. The actual items can be viewed on the dropdown Item HTML DOC image. I am hoping to loop through the the dropdown list. @Tim Williams

Comment: @QHarr how would I select the item ?

Comment: I didn't notice the second image where indeed there are 'li' elements. I assume you need to target the child `a` tags within. However, I don't know what happens to the DOM after you click one as it may update. You can gather all those `a` elements with `ie.document.querySelectorAll("li[role=presentation] > a")` ; however, if the DOM updates after clicking the first, a loop over the nodeList returned by `ie.document.querySelectorAll("li[role=presentation] > a")` will likely throw an exception. Is this an internal website?

Comment: thank you @qharr this is an internal website. I was wondering how would I construct this into a loop  for the list of items  under the dropdown??

Comment: You can get the length of the dropdown items using `itemnum=ie.document.querySelectorAll("li[role=presentation] > a").Length`, then use `For i = 0 To itemnum` to loop through the items. You can refer to [For...Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) loop in VBA. You can choose a certain item using `ie.document.querySelectorAll("li[role=presentation] > a")(i)`. As we don't have access to your website, we can only give some suggestions and you can have a try.